# Change order of rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like this:

```
+-------+--------------------------------------+------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| SecID |               SecGuid                |    LevelType     |                      Description                       |
+-------+--------------------------------------+------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
|     1 | 550239E9-01A1-4403-8133-834DD0EBD7EA | Administrator    | All Access Pass                                        |
|     2 | 181104C8-2241-4E51-B73D-59D5E4E8C22D | Advanced Author  | Edit, create, delete, archive, pricing, and agreements |
|     3 | 24E50493-854C-4C44-A074-E6D2EAAC5E5C | Mid Level Author | Edit, create, delete and archive                       |
|     4 | 306C087D-F86A-43F6-B57A-8C65F9E8337D | Author           | Edit and create                                        |
|     5 | 9B66AE7D-B704-4D75-8776-774A2CFC0C47 | Contibutor       | Edit                                                   |
|     6 | 35B0F735-E240-47D0-9E33-694D6197C765 | Browser          | View                                                   |
|     7 | E3606250-F5C5-4DED-B29F-53E6C6C91FDA | Banned           | no access                                              |
|     8 | B0A0F8E1-93F3-431F-A7BF-95F14C22703E | Low Level Author | Edit, create, delete, archive, Task assignation        |
+-------+--------------------------------------+------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

But now I want to change my last row to be under third one and change `SecID` for  4 and of course change others under this row. So at the final, I want to achieve something like this:

```
+-------+--------------------------------------+------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| SecID |               SecGuid                |    LevelType     |                      Description                       |
+-------+--------------------------------------+------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
|     1 | 550239E9-01A1-4403-8133-834DD0EBD7EA | Administrator    | All Access Pass                                        |
|     2 | 181104C8-2241-4E51-B73D-59D5E4E8C22D | Advanced Author  | Edit, create, delete, archive, pricing, and agreements |
|     3 | 24E50493-854C-4C44-A074-E6D2EAAC5E5C | Mid Level Author | Edit, create, delete and archive                       |
|     4 | B0A0F8E1-93F3-431F-A7BF-95F14C22703E | Low Level Author | Edit, create, delete, archive, Task assignation        |
|     5 | 306C087D-F86A-43F6-B57A-8C65F9E8337D | Author           | Edit and create                                        |
|     6 | 9B66AE7D-B704-4D75-8776-774A2CFC0C47 | Contibutor       | Edit                                                   |
|     7 | 35B0F735-E240-47D0-9E33-694D6197C765 | Browser          | View                                                   |
|     8 | E3606250-F5C5-4DED-B29F-53E6C6C91FDA | Banned           | no access                                              |
+-------+--------------------------------------+------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

NOTE: Table have a constraint and `SecID` is a primary key:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SecAccess] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_SecAccess_SecGuid]  DEFAULT (newid()) FOR [SecGuid]
```

Comment: dup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812630/how-can-i-reorder-rows-in-sql-database

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I reorder rows in sql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812630/how-can-i-reorder-rows-in-sql-database)

Comment: Some other examples of moving a row up, down and swapping rows are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48327539/manage-records-ordering/48329605#48329605).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, move down rows starting from 4:

```
UPDATE dbo.SecAccess SET SecID = SecID + 1 WHERE SecID > 3;
```

Then move the last row, now having the no. 9 to row 4:

```
UPDATE dbo.SecAccess SET SecID = 4 WHERE SecID = 9;
```

This assumes that `SecID`is not an **indentity column**. If it is one then do

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.SecAccess ON;
UPDATE dbo.SecAccess SET SecID = SecID + 1 WHERE SecID > 3;
UPDATE dbo.SecAccess SET SecID = 4 WHERE SecID = 9;
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.SecAccess OFF;
```

See:  [SET IDENTITY_INSERT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

---

A solution giving you more flexibility is to introduce a new column solely used for sorting

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.SecAccess ADD SortOrder int;
UPDATE dbo.SecAccess SET SortOrder = CASE 
                                       WHEN SecID = 8 THEN 4
                                       WHEN SecID > 3 THEN SecID + 1
                                       ELSE SecID
                                     END;
```

Comment: I try but I get Cannot update identity column 'SecID'

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try:

```
update SecTable set SecID = 0 where SecID = 8;
update SecTable set SecID += 1 where SecID in (4,5,6,7);
update SetTable set SecID = 4 where SecID = 0;
```

Comment: No sir I have a constraint there, First I remove it, then I try what you said and I get 'Cannot update identity column 'SecID'.'

Comment: obviously then, you'd need to set identity insert on and off again after.